# Merge contacts loses relationships

Tags: duplicate-contacts

When I merge two contacts I lose relationship info on both 4.6.5 and 4.7.3 The relationships come up as inactive with the current date as the end of the relationship. I don't see any errors except relationships are 0 after the merge and the relationships are shown as inactive

I did some research which points to a possible schema issue which suggests you verify the schema.  I am somewhat concerned about doing that, especially where I need to merge 2 records, if it fails I either need to recover the database or find a new pair of records to merge.

I am looking at upgrading to 4.7.8 but not sure there are additional fixes which will resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi - a little more information might be helpful for folks who want to troubleshoot this with you.  For example, did the two contacts have relationships of the same type (e.g., both contact A and contact B had "Employee of" relationships)?  Or were they different?  I tested this quickly on the 4.6.x demo site with relationships of different types and was unable to replicate the issue.